# How to remove data- attribute from the div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html `div` element, which contains lot of HTML-5 `data-` attributes to store extra

data with element. I know that we can use `removeAttr` of jquery to remove specific attribute,

but i want to know that is there any way to remove `data-` all atonce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have to loop through them and remove them individually. E.g.:

```
var $div = $("selector for the div"),
    attrs = $div[0].attributes,
    name,
    index;
for (index = attrs.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    name = attrs[index].nodeName;
    if (name.substring(0, 5) === "data-") {
        $div.removeAttr(name);
    }
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/abukon) | [source](http://jsbin.com/abukon/edit)

...or something along those lines.

Answer (score 6):

Not aware of any wholesale way of doing this. You'd have to loop over the element's attributes with something like

```
var el = document.querySelector('p');
for (var i=0; i<el.attributes.length; i++)
    if (/^data-/i.test(el.attributes[i].name))
        el.removeAttribute(el.attributes[i].name);
```

Comment: Likewise you - not far away!

Comment: there's an error here, when you remove the attribute, the index changes, so you may skip two data attributes in a row. you have to `{ el.removeAttribute(el.attributes[i].name); i--; }` or loop from the last to first